# Press and hold the back button from the program

Tags: java, android

I want to execute long press of back button from Android program.
I am running the following program, but onKeyLongPress is not called.
How do I execute long press of back button from Android program ?

I use an emulator called **Genymotion**.

- MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.input.InputManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.InputEvent;
import android.view.KeyCharacterMap;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    InputManager inputManager = (InputManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_SERVICE);
                    Method injectInputEvent = InputManager.class.getMethod("injectInputEvent", InputEvent.class, int.class);

                    long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

                    KeyEvent eventDown = new KeyEvent(
                            now, (now + 2000), KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, 1, 0,
                            KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0, KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS);

                    injectInputEvent.invoke(inputManager,eventDown, 0);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("********* Called ********");
        return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

- AndroidManifest.xml
  I added the following.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.
change "repeat" and execute twice.

```
for (int repeat = 0; repeat <= 1; repeat++) {
    KeyEvent eventDown1 = new KeyEvent(
            now, (now + 2000), KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, repeat, 0,
            KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0, KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS);
    injectInputEvent.invoke(inputManager, eventDown1, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("", "Longpress detected");
    }
});

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. But that's not what I want to do.